# how to change the button text color on AlertDialog globally using style?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-styles, material-components-android

on android O when i do this :

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"> 

    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>

  </style>
```

The text button color of my alertdialog change, but this not work under lollipop. Worse on lollipop it's change the color of the title of the alertdialog instead.

How from kitkat to android O I can globally change the font color of the button of all my alertdialog ?

Comment: you can add the  AlertDialog code?

Comment: @chetanmahajan i don't want to touch the alertdialog code, I only want to touch the style. i do it like mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, null/*listener*/, 2000/*year*/, 1/*month*/, 1/*dayOfMonth*/);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the MaterialComponents theme and the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` you can define globally the style using the **`materialAlertDialogTheme`** attribute in your app theme.

Something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/My_MaterialAlertDialog</item>
</style>
```

Then you can define a custom style:

```
  <style name="My_MaterialAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <!-- Style for positive button -->
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    <!-- Style for negative button -->
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
    <!-- Style for neutral button -->
    <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/NeutralButtonStyle</item>
  </style>
```

with the button style defined by:

```
  <style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
  </style>

  <style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
  </style>

  <style name="NueutralButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    ....
  </style>
```

With the version **1.1.0** of the library you can also simply override the default color using the **`materialThemeOverlay`** in the custom style:

```
  <style name="My_MaterialAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
      <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/DialogButtonOverlay</item>
  </style>

  <style name="DialogButtonOverlay">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: not working
I am using   'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'

Comment: @AbrahamMathew Use 1.1.0-beta02

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a theme for AlertDialog and set it to AppTheme. It will change you alet dialog theme globally.

```
<style name="AppAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    ...
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppAlertDialog</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Java Class for your custom alert dialog

```
public class Dialog {
    private static final int resId = R.layout.dialog_dialog;
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;

    /**
     * Custom Dialog
     *
     * @param context
     * @param titleText
     * @param message
     * @param positiveText
     * @param negativeText
     * @param type
     * @param dialogListener
     */
    public Dialog(final Context context,
                  String titleText,
                  String message,
                  String positiveText,
                  String negativeText,
                  Type type,
                  final DialogListener dialogListener) {
        TextView labelTitle, labelMessage, buttonPositive, buttonNegative;
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resId, null, false);
        labelTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.labelTitle);
        labelMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.labelMessage);
        buttonPositive = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonPositive);
        buttonNegative = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonNegative);
        if (Utils.isNotEmpty(titleText)) labelTitle.setText(titleText); //(HMI2Utils.isNotEmpty is a null check
        if (Utils.isNotEmpty(message)) labelMessage.setText(message);
        if (Utils.isNotEmpty(positiveText)) buttonPositive.setText(positiveText);
        if (Utils.isNotEmpty(negativeText)) buttonNegative.setText(negativeText);
        switch (type) {
            case DANGEROUS:
                labelTitle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
        }
        buttonNegative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
                dialogListener.onNegativeButtonClick();
            }
        });
        buttonPositive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
                dialogListener.onPositiveButtonClick();
            }
        });
        Utils.hideSoftKeyboard((Activity) context);
        ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        Window window = alertDialog.getWindow();
        if (window != null) {
            window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.app_theme_color));
        }
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

and for xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlRoot"
    android:layout_width="736.15px"
    android:layout_height="532.66px"
    tools:ignore="Overdraw">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/focus_eater_dummy"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="736.15px"
        android:layout_height="532.66px"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="your drawable" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="736.15px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="67.83px"
            android:layout_marginRight="67.83px"
            android:layout_marginTop="57.855px"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/labelTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/delete_message_string"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/labelMessage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="18px"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="18px"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1"
                android:text="@string/delete_message_string"
                android:textColor="@color/white"

                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerButtons"
        android:layout_width="736.15px"
        android:layout_height="532.66px"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buttonPositive"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_button_vertical_dai"

            android:background="@drawable/popup_button_selector"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            tools:text="OK" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buttonNegative"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/popup_button_selector"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="32sp" />
         </LinearLayout>
         </FrameLayout>
```

make your custom changes and call the dialog like

```
                   new Dialog(context,
                    "Title 1",
                    "Message 2",
                    "OK",
                    "Cancel",
                    Dialog.Type.DANGEROUS,
                    new Dialog.DialogListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPositiveButtonClick() {
                            //implement Click here
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNegativeButtonClick() {
                                 //implement Click here
                        }
                    }
            );
            dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: no, i don't want to create a custom class, i want to change the design of all existing alertdialog, i don't want to reprogram them